# How do you add a tag to Sentry reports?

Tags: java, sentry

Alright, so I want to add some user identification to our sentry reports.

Using Spring, we have our `OidcUserService` that loads the users...

```
public class MyOidcUserService extends OidcUserService {

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        var sentry = Sentry.getStoredClient();
        var sContext = Sentry.getContext();

        sentry.addTag("user", "<unauthenticated>");
        sContext.addTag("user", "<context: unauthenticated>");

        var authenticatedUser = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        checkRoles(authenticatedUser);
        var user = getOrCreateUser(authenticatedUser); //MyOidcUser

        sentry.addTag("user", user.getPerson().getThreeLetterCode());
        sContext.addTag("user", "context: " + user.getPerson().getThreeLetterCode());

        if (true) throw new RuntimeException("This really should show the tag ...");
        return user;
    }

    ...
}
```

What happens, though, is that the exceptions shows up on `sentry`, alright, but the `user` tag is missing.

Why? And how do I add the darn thing?

Answer (score 2):

Please look at https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/integrations/#usage
it should be something like:

```
// Set the user in the current context.
Sentry.getContext().setUser(
     new UserBuilder().setEmail("a@a.com").build()
);
```

Comment: That's what I eventually ended up doing. But I still don't understand why the tag didn't work.